# Numpy meshgrid keep bottom layer an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, mesh

I want to make a meshgrid, but keep the bottom layer an array.

When I do this:

```
One = np.array([["1A1","1A2"],["1B1","1B2"]])
Two = np.array([["2A1","2A2"],["2B1","2B2"]])
np.array(np.meshgrid(One, Two))
```

I get:

```
array([[['1A1', '1A2', '1B1', '1B2'],
        ['1A1', '1A2', '1B1', '1B2'],
        ['1A1', '1A2', '1B1', '1B2'],
        ['1A1', '1A2', '1B1', '1B2']],

       [['2A1', '2A1', '2A1', '2A1'],
        ['2A2', '2A2', '2A2', '2A2'],
        ['2B1', '2B1', '2B1', '2B1'],
        ['2B2', '2B2', '2B2', '2B2']]], dtype='<U3')
```

But I don't want to get all the Strings separately. I want the basic structure of `["1A1","1A2"]` not to be split up.

Basically, what I am looking for is something, that results in this:

```
array([[[['1A1', '1A2'],['1B1', '1B2']],
        [['1A1', '1A2'],['1B1', '1B2']]],

       [[['2A1', '2A2'],['2A1', '2A2']],
        [['2B1', '2B2'],['2B1', '2B2']]]], dtype='<U3')
```

Is there a function or other way to achieve that?

EDIT:
The strings are just there to make it easier to understand. I will use this with `ints` if there are any other methods.

Comment: `meshgrid` does say that the inputs are "**1-D arrays** representing the coordinates of a grid."  You gave it 2d ones, which it flattened.

Comment: That's why I'm looking for a function that doesn't flatten it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach is to make object dtype arrays with the units you want to keep together as elements:

```
In [82]: One_ = np.empty(2,object)                                                                   
In [84]: One_[:] = One.tolist()                                                                      
In [85]: One_                                                                                        
Out[85]: array([list(['1A1', '1A2']), list(['1B1', '1B2'])], dtype=object)

In [86]: Two_ = np.empty(2,object)                                                                   
In [87]: Two_[:] = Two.tolist()
```

Now `meshgrid` can combine them, just as it would with numeric or string dtypes:

```
In [88]: np.meshgrid(One_, Two_)                                                                     
Out[88]: 
[array([[list(['1A1', '1A2']), list(['1B1', '1B2'])],
        [list(['1A1', '1A2']), list(['1B1', '1B2'])]], dtype=object),
 array([[list(['2A1', '2A2']), list(['2A1', '2A2'])],
        [list(['2B1', '2B2']), list(['2B1', '2B2'])]], dtype=object)]
```

and as one array:

```
In [89]: np.stack(_)                                                                                 
Out[89]: 
array([[[list(['1A1', '1A2']), list(['1B1', '1B2'])],
        [list(['1A1', '1A2']), list(['1B1', '1B2'])]],

       [[list(['2A1', '2A2']), list(['2A1', '2A2'])],
        [list(['2B1', '2B2']), list(['2B1', '2B2'])]]], dtype=object)
```

And conversion back to string array:

```
In [90]: np.array(_.tolist())                                                                        
Out[90]: 
array([[[['1A1', '1A2'],
         ['1B1', '1B2']],

        [['1A1', '1A2'],
         ['1B1', '1B2']]],


       [[['2A1', '2A2'],
         ['2A1', '2A2']],

        [['2B1', '2B2'],
         ['2B1', '2B2']]]], dtype='<U3')
```

Or use a structured array view to group the two strings:

```
In [92]: One.view([('f0','U3',(2,))])                                                                
Out[92]: 
array([[(['1A1', '1A2'],)],
       [(['1B1', '1B2'],)]], dtype=[('f0', '<U3', (2,))])
In [93]: Two.view([('f0','U3',(2,))])                                                                
Out[93]: 
array([[(['2A1', '2A2'],)],
       [(['2B1', '2B2'],)]], dtype=[('f0', '<U3', (2,))])
In [94]: np.meshgrid(_92, _93)                                                                       
Out[94]: 
[array([[(['1A1', '1A2'],), (['1B1', '1B2'],)],
        [(['1A1', '1A2'],), (['1B1', '1B2'],)]],
       dtype=[('f0', '<U3', (2,))]),
 array([[(['2A1', '2A2'],), (['2A1', '2A2'],)],
        [(['2B1', '2B2'],), (['2B1', '2B2'],)]],
       dtype=[('f0', '<U3', (2,))])]
In [95]: np.stack(_)                                                                                 
Out[95]: 
array([[[(['1A1', '1A2'],), (['1B1', '1B2'],)],
        [(['1A1', '1A2'],), (['1B1', '1B2'],)]],

       [[(['2A1', '2A2'],), (['2A1', '2A2'],)],
        [(['2B1', '2B2'],), (['2B1', '2B2'],)]]],
      dtype=[('f0', '<U3', (2,))])
In [96]: import numpy.lib.recfunctions as rf                                                         
In [97]: rf.structured_to_unstructured(_95)                                                          
Out[97]: 
array([[[['1A1', '1A2'],
         ['1B1', '1B2']],

        [['1A1', '1A2'],
         ['1B1', '1B2']]],


       [[['2A1', '2A2'],
         ['2A1', '2A2']],

        [['2B1', '2B2'],
         ['2B1', '2B2']]]], dtype='<U3')
```

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Your layout is a bit unusual, but this repeated stack seems to do the job:

```
In [79]: np.stack((np.stack((One,One)), np.stack((Two,Two))))                                        
Out[79]: 
array([[[['1A1', '1A2'],
         ['1B1', '1B2']],

        [['1A1', '1A2'],
         ['1B1', '1B2']]],


       [[['2A1', '2A2'],
         ['2B1', '2B2']],

        [['2A1', '2A2'],
         ['2B1', '2B2']]]], dtype='<U3')
```

Comment: That is a good suggestion, but if you look closely your second stack is the same layout as the first stack, what meshgrid does is it flips the second one, so instead of ABAB you get AABB

Comment: I was focused on matching the `Ones`. Looks like the `Twos` needs some sort of transpose.

Answer (score 0):

The two comments(@hpaulj, @Richard K Yu) that were made both had a small mistake, but fortunately they made a different mistake, so I could merge their ideas to create a solution. My solution is:

```
np.array([np.stack((One,One)),np.array(np.meshgrid(*Two))])
```

However, if someone knows a more elegant solution, I would be very happy, because it is kind of clumpy at the moment.